# Can you please tell where am I going wrong?

Tags: java, javafx

I have PNG folder in src. 
I have ImageStore class which has HashMap 
Assigning the image with string in main class
And I am trying to retrieve images from HashMap from ImageStore and assign it to each card in cardClass.Java
But my problem is while retrieving the images in cardClass, it returns null.

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {
 @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
   Parent root = 
   FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
   primaryStage.setTitle("Card");
   primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
   primaryStage.show();
   loadimages();
   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
//In load images I am loading the images and mapping with string for ImageStore HashMap
    public void loadimages() {
        String[] rank = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
        String[] suit = {"Heart", "Diamond", "Spade", "Club"};
        for (int i = 0; i < suit.length; i++) {
            //  ImageStore.cardimagedeck.put(rank[j]+suit[i],new Image("@PNG/"+rank[j]+suit[i]+".png"));
            for (int j = 0; j < rank.length; j++) {
                File file = new File("Users/Nithyaprakash/Desktop/JAVAFX/Card/src/sample/PNG/" + rank[j] + suit[i] + ".png");
                Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
                if (image != null) {
                    ImageStore.cardimagedeck.put(rank[j] + suit[i], image);

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

DeckOfCards:

```
  public DeckOfCards()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<12;j++)
            {


                    deck.add(new cardClass(j,i));
                }
            }
        }
```

CardClass:

```
public class cardClass extends ImageView {
    enum suit{Heart,Diamond,Spade,Club}
    enum rank
    {Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten,Jack,Queen,King,Ace}

    private rank cardrank;
    private suit cardsuit;
    private Image cardimage;
    public cardClass(int r,int s)
    {
        this.cardrank= rank.values()[r];
        this.cardsuit=suit.values()[s];
       cardimage=ImageStore.cardimagedeck.get(cardrank.name()+cardsuit.name());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  cardrank +
                " of " + cardsuit ;
    }
}
```

ImageStore Class :

```
public class ImageStore {
    static HashMap<String, Image> cardimagedeck=new HashMap<>();


    public static HashMap<String, Image> getCardimagedeck() {
        return cardimagedeck;
    }

    public static void setCardimagedeck(HashMap<String, Image> cardimagedeck) {
        ImageStore.cardimagedeck = cardimagedeck;
    }

}
```

Here you can check the left panel for PNG folder and the images for each card.

[image]

Comment: Title tells nothing about the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Where do you check for `null`? BTW: note that 1) Checking a variable for `null` in the same scope just after assigning the result of executing a constructor is unnecessary: Either the constructor completion completes normally resulting in a non-null value or it yields an exception which exits the scope before the test can be performed. 2) The intention of the file path seems to be to use an absolute path. The path seems to be lacking the drive letter or starting `/` though. 3) You load the images at the very end of the `start` method. Any code running before does not have access to the values.

Comment: Try `URL url = Main.class.getResource("/sample/PNG/"+rank[j] + suit[i] + ".png");   Image image = new Image(url.openStream());`

Comment: Furthermore you do not assign the image to the `image` property of your `ImageView` subclass. Also your deck leaves out aces and you should try to store the images as resources. I recommend using code that s a little different to c0der's though: `new Image(Main.class.getResource("/sample/PNG/" + suit[j]+rank[j]+".png").toExternalForm());`; This makes the url available via a property for javafx 9+ which could be useful for debugging.